# Find an exact match from search in array of objects using mongodb

Tags: jquery, angularjs, filter, underscore.js

I'm querying for all of the data in my database and running a search against it using the following code.

The problem is that it doesn't query for an exact match, it's a keyword search.
If I enter "dog colorado" it returns all results containing the words "dog" and "colorado".

I'd like it to return results for "dog colorado".

I am using Mongodb for reference

```
$http.get('/sapi/search/contractors?query=' + $scope.data.query)
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log("response from query", res.data);
    // if it gets all the data
    if (res.data.users && res.data.users.length) {
      $scope.items = _.filter(res.data.users, function(user) {
        return user.roles && user.roles.indexOf('contractor') !== -1 && user.firstName;
      });
    } else {
      console.log('no items', res);
      $scope.items = null;
    }
```

Comment: are you wanting help with the backend service? you will need to provide that code.

Comment: I think the filtering can be done on the frontend @JoshuaJWilborn. I assume that there is an issue with my return statement. I'd like it to function as follows "return the data that is an exact match to the search"

Comment: but if you are providing the search parameters to the backend, why is it returning everything? Or you want it to return everything that matches both words and then filter it down to an exact match on the front? I don't feel your question is exact enough.

Comment: fair enough @JoshuaJWilborn. I guess a more specific question is how can i query for an exact match on the backend? What code can I show to get some help

Comment: Alright, amend your question with the backend framework type, the relevant route, and the type of database you are interacting with.  Then add your specific question as well.  Thanks.

Comment: i think first u should what data is comming in $scope.data.query. Is it a string or string array if you type more than one word in search textbox and then check your database query.

Comment: @MukulSharma It's an object that contains multiple arrays of user data

Comment: you should pass a complete string not array so that it could match exact value in database table.

Comment: @MukulSharma how can i pass the complete string? In the code above, `$scope.data.query` represents what is typed in my search form. Sorry for the confusion. So for example, if i typed "dog" in the search, that would equal `$scope.data.query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright you are using mongodb, so you need to use the mongo querying system with a regex to get exact match.

```
db.collection.find({yourattributeyouwanttomatch: {$regex: new RegExp('^' +  query + '$', 'i')}})
```

You can remove the 'i' if you want case sensitive and you can remove the ^ and $ if you want to match anywhere in the string.

Comment: Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to search from array of object in mongo
for eg:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  persons: [
            { name: 'ABC',
              age: 10
            },
            { name: 'ABD',
              age: 12
            }
          ]
}
```

mongo query:

```js
db.users.find({person: {$elemMatch: {name:'ABC', age:10}}})
```